# How can I have a total row appear at the bottom of a table of a variable size?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a table with a variable number of rows. I'd like for there to be total row beneath it.

The rows are being generated by a function producing an array. So my current solution is to have enough blank rows so that the total row is far enough away that the array won't collide with the total row. But that obviously leaves a lot of blank rows.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: At the most basic level, you can do this using VSTACK.  Your array of data is the first argument, and then a horizontal array with the same number of columns that contains all your totals is the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just checking, are you actually using the Excel Table feature? If you format your data as a table (which can have variable length too) there is an option to add a "Total row" under the "Table Design" ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formula approach, use matrix multiplication. It might be a bit tricky to do, but create an identity matrix with one extra row of ones beneath it. E.g. say your data is

```
1
2
3
```

And the "ID with total" matrix is

```
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
1  1  1
```

Then

```
=MMULT(ID with total, data vector)
```

Will give

```
1
2
3
6
```

To create the matrix easily you would need Excel 365 with the MAKEARRAY function:

```
=MAKEARRAY(4, 3, LAMBDA(r, c, IF(r>3, 1, IF(r=c, 1, 0))))
```

Comment: That or just add the total row on top 